# is positioning with javascript a good practice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just learned javascript and jquery a few weeks ago, since then I always use it to position all my divs and stuff in the screen by knowing the size of the screen and the window which I find extremely useful, but now I don't know if is this a good practice, cause it makes my web-pages fully dependant on jquery which I don't know if it may cause some troubles with different browsers.
I would really like to find answers like "Sure is a good practice, use all the scripts you want" cause I'm really loving this javascript stuff but well just tell what you think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I'm going to burst your bubble, somewhat.

It's somewhat OK to do it - as long as the page looks OK if you disable Javascript, as well. I would say it should look even better than OK. I would also say that you should only do that if the *functionality* of your site really demands Javascript, as well.

Keep in mind that a certain percentage of users will have Javascript disabled. I've seen sites that look *horrible* this way (I use NoScript on Firefox, and selectively enable Javascript as I browser), and a couple where *nothing at all appears* without JS enabled.

Bad.

As Darin notes, you can (and should!) use CSS for positioning and styling. That is what it was made for! Feel free to enhance the page with Javascript, but keep in mind what I say above!

Comment: This is not a good practice. I don't want to hunt down styling that is set from JavaScript. My tooling can help me find stuff in CSS not in JS.

Comment: @Bart ... **if** the page looks OK without it, as well. **And**, I go on to say only if the *functionality* of the page also demands Javascript. I even start off saying, "I'm going to burst your bubble..."

Answer (score 6):

Use JavaScript for behaviors and CSS for styling.

Styling with JavaScript is slower and difficult for another developer/designer to figure out what you did.

Also if you use Firebug or Chrome Web Inspector you can not see where your styling is coming from.

Optionally set classes from JavaScript and not specific styling. You can transition between classes to create a nice effect. But at least your colleague can see where the styles are defined and change it.

Comment: I agree with this answer, despite what might seem to be disagreement suggested by the comments to mine.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) for positioning and styling of elements. That's what it was designed for.

Answer (score 2):

It's okay to use it for positioning in some cases, but using CSS is the better practice whenever applicable.

Answer (score 2):

Well, In my opinion you should avoid it as often as possible. But I know sometime you don't have the choice.

And yea you can make great web apps using scripts.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you're positioning.

CSS should be your first choice for positioning standard, run-of-the-mill sections and elements of a webpage. To opt for JavaScript in these cases suggests a lack of understanding of CSS.

Likewise if you find yourself using JS to position things for different devices. Again, CSS has evolved; media queries came along for that. Rule: always exhaust CSS possibilities first.

That said, it would be oversimplification to suggest that JavaScript never be used for positioning. All of us, rightly or wrongly, have resorted (and it is just that, resorting) to JS in order to get things to look right cross-browser, particularly where support for older IEs is concerned.

But by far the biggest use case for JS positioning is for modern web aps and games. If you're building a game with random asteroids dotted around, JS is absolutely the choice for that, since the positions are based on calculation and computation.

Finally, bear in mind that when you position in JS, you are of course still using CSS. JS doesn't have its own, concurrent styling/positioning system - it simply sets CSS properties. It is simply able to do so more dynamically and conditionally than flat CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost certainly bad practise. Use CSS for styling - JavaScript to do this is slower, more work, and more prone to breaking.

Answer (score 0):

If you're positioning everything absolutely (fixed coordinates) it won't look good on screens of different resolutions. There's no real answer to this question.. scripts have their place, and you can use all the scripts you want... Positioning all of the elements of your layout, however, is not a job for JS. Use CSS for that.

I'd start here: [Starting with HTML + CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss.en.html)

Answer (score -1):

There is not one method for all situations. Each web application needs to employ the right tools and practices to achieve its goals. This varies so much between applications that there is not a "correct" answer to your question.

Comment: There is a right answer to a point. You would never suggest opting for JS for styling major site sections or elements. Likewise, you would not suggest CSS for games or other applications where positioning or styling is perhaps too dynamic to be achieved via flat, non-dynamic CSS files.